# Unable to install go tools on WSL

Tags: go

I am trying to install go tools in my WSL
command :
`go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls`

Error :

```
 go get: module golang.org/x/tools/gopls: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/golang.org/x/tools/gopls/@v/list": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

**Error Msg : x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

Comment: Are you behind a corporate network. The certificate presented by the proxy.golang.org is a regular GlobalSign CA which should be trusted by an standard OS distribution. If it doesn't, then you can simply add this CA to your Linux distro's truststore. https://askubuntu.com/a/94861 or search for the specific distro you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I could not turn off NetScope as suggested. (no privileges)

Summing other answers made a script, it works for Ubuntu (wsl2 for Windows)

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
true | openssl s_client -connect $1:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 > $1.pem
mv $1.pem $1.crt
sudo mv $1.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/$1.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Usage

`sudo ./ca_resolver.sh proxy.golang.org`

If you add script path to *.profile* or *.bashrc* or *.zshrc*

`export PATH=~/scripts/:$PATH`

It is easier

`sudo ca_resolver.sh proxy.golang.org`

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is similar to [`golang/go` issue 45569](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45569), and check the ouput of

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect proxy.golang.org:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -text -noout
```

In that issue, behind a corporate network, disabling [NetScope](https://www.netskope.com/) was needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because in a clean WSL with only golang installed.
Try install ca-certificates, it may solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30332915)